# How can I specify the hostname in a call to a WCF service in .NET Core?

Tags: wcf, .net-core

I'm trying to call a WCF service.  I have the following constraints:

- The client doesn't have access to a DNS
- The client code is .NET Core, running on Linux
- The WCF service (IIS) requires the client to use the hostname
- The IP address changes, so the client gets the latest IP address whenever it makes a call to the service

Based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10985582/394157), it is possible to set the host in a header, but I haven't been able to specify a header when doing a call to WCF in .NET Core.

I assume I should do something like this to pass the hostname in the *host* header, but `WebOperationContext` doesn't seem to exist in .NET Core:

```
var svc = new ServiceClient(ServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService,
    new EndpointAddress($"http://{GetLatestIP()}/Service.svc"));

using (new OperationContextScope(((ServiceClient)svc).InnerChannel))
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("host", "myurl");
    var response = svc.GetResponseAsync(request).Result;
}
```

Any ideas how I can pass a header to a WCF service, using .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring the ServiceClient which got generated. It must be having a method to specify the remote server address.

Comment: I can specify the address.  The problem is that I have to send the IP and the hostname, because the client doesn't have access to a DNS.  Does that make sense?

Comment: When you say, client doesn't have an access to DNS, what do you mean? Is your server accessible from internet or just intranet ?